# Installing TIBCO to build an EAR file

Tags: installation, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer, tibco-topic

I'm trying to install TIBCO using the universal installer, and passing in the silent file. However, whenever I run these commands:

```
./tibco_universal_installer_filename -silent -V responseFile=silent_file.silent -is:tempdir /opt/tmp
```

I don't get any output and nothing seems to be happening (eg. No folders created, no Tibco installed)

I'm sure I'm missing something here. :/ Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I don't plan to install the whole TIBCO stack but just the files needed to build EAR files, would that be possible?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

1- Try this silent file and put it in the same folder then installer. Then just execute:

```
  ./$installer_bin_file -silent
```

Silent File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>---Universal Installer Silent Installation Properties---</comment>

<!--accept the license agreement-->
<entry key="acceptLicense">true</entry>

<!--the root installation directory-->
<!--if the product does not support multiple instances and TIBCO_HOME has already been set then-->
<!--this value is ignored and the existing TIBCO_HOME is used as the installation root-->
<entry key="installationRoot">/opt/tibco</entry>

<!--If using an existing environment then the installationRoot AND environmentName MUST match a pre-existing environment-->
<!--If creating a new environment then the installationRoot AND environmentName MUST BE UNIQUE and not match a pre-existing environment-->
<entry key="environmentName">TIBCO_HOME</entry>

<!-- The following configuration parameters control the download of all LGPL components used by BW, e.g. Hibernate -->
<!-- LGPLAssemblyLicenseAccepted - true or false to accept the license -->
<!-- LGPLAssemblyDownload - true or false to download the assembly from the public tibco server -->
<!-- LGPLAssemblyPath - if LGPLAssemblyDownload is false, this is the path where the LGPL assembly is located on the system (note that all LGPL assemblies must be in the same directory -->
<entry key="LGPLAssemblyLicenseAccepted">true</entry>
<entry key="LGPLAssemblyDownload">false</entry>
<entry key="LGPLAssemblyPath">/opt/src</entry>

<!--Profiles Selection-->
<!-- The 'selectedProfiles' value is a comma separated list of profiles to install. If a profile is listed which does not exist, then it is ignored and the default profile will be used. At least one profile must be listed if useInstallProfile is set to true -->
<entry key="useInstallProfile">true</entry>
<entry key="selectedProfiles">Typical</entry>

</properties>
```

2- If not succeeded, try console option to validate your system environment (memory, disk etc ...).

3- Yes you can install only EMS and BW components to deploy your APP, but install TEA also for administration purposes.

B.B